# JS / jQuery - How do I get the text of two DIV content at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to loop trough all `<TD>` elements where I want to write the `Title` and `Link` of the same `<TD>` element in two variables. How can I do that in JS / jQuery?

**My HTML:**

```
<td>
    <div class="class_Title row border-bottom" name="name_Title" id="id_Title">
        <B>Microsoft</B>
    </div>
    <div class="class_Link row" name="name_Link" id="id_Link">
        https://www.microsoft.com
    </div>
</td>

<td>
    <div class="class_Title row border-bottom" name="name_Title" id="id_Title">
        <B>Google</B>
    </div>
    <div class="class_Link row" name="name_Link" id="id_Link">
        https://www.google.com
    </div>
</td>
<!-- there are a lot of these...-->
```

**My Javascript:**

```
    $('.class_Title').each(function(){
        var str_CurrentTitle = '';
        str_CurrentTitle= $(this).text().trim()

        $('.class_Link').each(function(){
            var str_CurrentLink = '';
            str_CurrentLink= $(this).text().trim()

            //call another function, to work with the result
            Start_To_Work_With_The_Result(str_CurrentTitle, str_CurrentLink)
        })
    })
```

Expected result is, that I can call the function Start_To_Work_With_The_Result once with the parameters (Microsoft / https://www.microsoft.com) and in the second loop with the paramters (Google / https://www.google.com).

How can I solve this in a elegant way?

Comment: Probably shouldn't be reusing `id` properties on the same page. The `id` DOM element property is meant to be unique to that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nested loops are getting every combination of title and link, not just the related pairs.

You should just have one loop, and then use a DOM navigation method to get the sibling element.

```js
$(".class_Title").each(function() {
  var str_CurrentTitle = $(this).text().trim();
  var link = $(this).siblings(".class_Link");
  var str_CurrentLink = link.text().trim();
  Start_To_Work_With_The_Result(str_CurrentTitle, str_CurrentLink);
});

function Start_To_Work_With_The_Result(title, link) {
  console.log(title, link);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
<td>
  <div class="class_Title row border-bottom" name="name_Title" id="id_Title">
    <B>Microsoft</B>
  </div>
  <div class="class_Link row" name="name_Link" id="id_Link">
    https://www.microsoft.com
  </div>
</td>

<td>
  <div class="class_Title row border-bottom" name="name_Title" id="id_Title">
    <B>Google</B>
  </div>
  <div class="class_Link row" name="name_Link" id="id_Link">
    https://www.google.com
  </div>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Your answer is on point, the original JS does not what it should do.

Comment: Doesn't work. The result is both title (Microsoft and Google). I would like to have first the title than the link of the title.

Comment: @EmbaBakar are you sure you don't messed up the code? looks correct to me

Comment: is it possible to post a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've added an executable snippet to the answer. I had to add the `<table><tr>...</tr></table>` around it to get proper results.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following? This will loop through all of the `td` elements, and get the data you need. Instead of having nested loops.

```
$('td').each(function(){
    var str_CurrentTitle = $(this).children(".class_Title").text().trim();
    var str_CurrentLink = $(this).children(".class_Link").text().trim();

    //call another function, to work with the result
    Start_To_Work_With_The_Result(str_CurrentTitle, str_CurrentLink)
})
```

This assumes that all of your `div` elements you want to access within the `td` elements have the classes `class_Title` and `class_Link`.

Comment: this might not work if there are also divs which don't have the OPs classes, empty cells or different constructed cell content

Comment: @thex Due to the fact that the OP was trying to do `.each` methods on each of those classes, I assume that all of the divs the OP wants to access have those classes.

Comment: The OP also has a wrong nested `.each` so I wouldn't assume too much, but there is nothing wrong with your solution

Comment: @thex Good point. And I believe a good answer should address those edge cases.  So I just added a section to my answer to explain that condition is a requirement for the answer.

Comment: what does mean a nested `.each`? And even that, unfortunately the code doesn't work in my case. Is it possible to specify the `td's` with a `ID` - to make sure, that only these `td` are in the loop?

Comment: @EmbaBakar You have a `.each` within a `.each`, which is bad for performance, and doesn't act how I think you are expecting it to act. `Is it possible to specify the td's with a ID - to make sure, that only these td are in the loop?`. I'm not sure what you mean by that. You mean limit it to not all `td`'s?

Comment: @EmbaBakar nested means in your case that you iterate in each iteration of your title extraction also every link, that is not what you actually want. You don't need an `ID` on your `<td>`

Comment: @CharlieFish Thanks for the information, now I know what you mean. And yes, I mean this to limit it to not loop trough all  `td `'s.

Comment: @EmbaBakar You could add a class to each `td`. Then instead of `$('td').each` you would do `$('td.myclassname').each` replacing `myclassname` with the class name you chose. That will select all td elements with the given class name.

Comment: @CharlieFish Thanks a lot - now I get it.